# getting array values ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array which is result of a query.

```
r = [
  #<Reservation id: 27, schedule_id: 1, name: "test user", gender: "no_answer",
    reservation_num: 1, zip: "", prefecture: "", address: "", street: "",
    tel: "", note: "", satisfied: true, canceled: false, seq: 27,
    created_at: "2019-08-28 06:04:30", updated_at: "2019-08-28 06:04:30",
    created_by: 2, updated_by: 2, from_partner: false, no_counting: false,
    reservation_time: nil, one_day_payment: nil, payment_id: 123456>
]
```

I want to get the payment_id but don't understand how should I write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have number of records in array, you can get `payment_id` in form of array as below,

```
r.map(&:payment_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should be able to select the first reservation from that array and then call on the `payment_id`. Like:

```
r.first.payment_id
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all payment_id's you can do

```
r.map(&:payment_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the collect method

```
r.collect(&:name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pluck payment ids (from the required set of data) with the following :

```
Reservation.pluck(:payment_id)
```

Comment: Even though your answer can be right is considered a low quality post because you should write an explanation such is "In ruby the way to retrieve..." which can be applied in the specific case in question  or to all cases. Also links to documentation help.

Comment: Noted with Thanks .